# autoreload and function decorator

Tags: ipython, decorator

I am fairly new to decorators but am experiencing unexpected behavior revolving around autoreload in an interactive workflow with decorated functions. Its best explained by example (note these are all cells in a jupyter notebook):

The decorator:

```
%%file testdec.py
def decorated(func):
    print("decorating")
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Where the decorator is used:

```
%%file testmod.py
from testdec import decorated
@decorated
def thisfunc():
    print("old output")
def _thisfunc1():
    print("old output 1")
thisfunc1 = decorated(_thisfunc1)
```

I would use the following to call the decorated functions:

```
from testmod import *
thisfunc()
thisfunc1()
```

outputs:

```
decorating
decorating
old output
old output 1
```

Now updating `testmod.py` with:

```
%%file testmod.py
from testdec import decorated
@decorated
def thisfunc():
    print("new output")
def _thisfunc1():
    print("new output 1")
thisfunc1 = decorated(_thisfunc1)
```

and calling the functions again:

```
thisfunc()
thisfunc1()
```

gives the following, note the old output from the first method:

```
decorating
decorating
old output
new output 1
```

However, explicitly reimporting from this module:

```
from testmod import *
thisfunc()
thisfunc1()
```

results in:

```
new output
new output 1
```

Ideally the `@decorated` function (e.g. with the `@` and not the second method) would autoreload transparently as the second method does. Is there something I can do to achieve this? What am I missing for decorated functions. For now we're manually disabling decorators when editing interactively in order to have the benefits of autoreload.

Thanks.